# How to create prototype that references a double located with in a struct located within a linked list?

Tags: c, function, data-structures, struct

I'm currently creating a program to interpolate linear regressions on missing entries in a time series. IE Col 2 Row 20-30 is missing the program would take col 2 row 19 (for instance 10) and col 2 row 30 (20) then fill in the NULL values linearly ie 11, 12, 13. I have multiple columns which have NULL values, so to do this I want to create a struct

```
struct missingPoint
{
  double lastVal;
  struct node * ptrtoLast;
  int missingVals;
};
struct point
{
  double col1;
  double col2;
  double col3;
};

typdef struct point Tick;

typedef struct node
{
  Tick tick;
  struct node * next;
 } Node;

typedef Node * List;
```

So the idea is to write a prototype then a function which takes *ptrtoList->tick.colx as an argument as well as the missingPoint struct then I can iterate it the col and fill in the missing time series data, it iterates the column storing ptrs to nodes which contain non-NULL entries for the Col, when it hits a NULL val, it has the ptr to the last node with non-null val, it iterates until it gets a non-Null value again then using the ptr it has stored in memory it iterates back through and replaces the Null values with a linear regression between the two poitns. But I don't know how I can specify a double which occurs inside a struct which is pointed to by another struct for a function and function prototype, with that function I could just call the function for every column I have, without it I'd have to hardcode quite a bit which I'd like to avoid. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

So the function would be like this, this currently has the column hard coded, I'd like to pass the column number as an argument so that I can multithread it, and call the function multiple times since the matrices I'm looking at are quite big, and because I'd like to practice concurrent programming:

```
void crawlOne(List *plist)
{
  Node * last;
  double lastVal, tmp;
  int i, count = 0;
  Node * pnode = *plist;
  while(pnode != NULL)
  {
    last = pnode->next;
    pnode = pnode->next;
    if(pnode->tick.col1=NULL)
    {
      while(pnode->tick.col1=NULL)
      {
        count ++;
        pnode = pnode->next;
      }
      tmp = lastVal-pnode->tick.col1;
      pnode = last;
      for(i=0;i<count;i++)
      {
        pnode = pnode->next;
        pnode->tick.col1 = lastVal + i*(tmp/count);
        i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want.  Could you write some pseudocode showing how you would want to call the function, and what should have changed when you finish?  (The very long sentences in your question make it hard to read and comprehend, by the way.  It also helps to use `backticks` to mark variable names and expressions in your writing.)

Comment: Sorry, lots of coffee and coke zero. Basic idea is I have a matrix. It's missing data in all of its columns. I want to write a program that fills in the data linearly, ie 3, X, 5; it would put 4, or 7, X, Y, 10, it would put 7, 8, 9, 10. The column data I have in a struct, the struct is pointed to by a pointer in a second struct which forms a linked list. I want to find a way to reference the columns so that I can write a general function and pass the columns to the function, so I won't have to hard code them. Hard coded their location is Node.tick.colX. Where both Node and tick are structs.

Comment: I believe you could search for an answer like: No, C does not have templates.

Comment: I actually don't know C++ so I'm not sure what a template is. But if It's not possible do you have any ideas or suggestions on how I can reorganize the code to work my way around this? Or do you think I should just hard code it all?

Comment: If you need three functions that are identical but for whether they access `col1`, `col2`, or `col3` of your structure type, then I would write a macro for such function definitions that takes the member name as a parameter.  That will ensure that the various versions cannot fall out of sync, and it will reinforce to readers (once they figure out what is going on) that the functions are indeed intended to match perfectly.

Comment: Alternatively, structuring the data differently might be a bigger win, especially if performance is a consideration.  Arrays are generally faster to access than linked lists, and column *numbers* are suitable for passing as function arguments.

Comment: `pnode = pnode->next;
    if(pnode->tick.col1=NULL)` pnode can be NULL here, and you are not testing for it. [and please don't hide pointers behind typedefs]

Answer (score 0):

- Generally: Just define the function multiple times. No, C doesn't have templates.
- The best: Generalize your data by providing an interface to manipulate it via function pointers - such interface is typically a [virtual table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). In your case a single function pointer to access the underlying data by a read/write handle looks enough. This effectively pulls the variant/changing/non-constant parts of the function into a different place. Allow users to pass an additional generic argument so that users can pass custom context:

```
void crawlOne(List *plist, double *(*getcol)(void *arg, struct point *p), void *arg)
{
      // tmp = lastVal-pnode->tick.col1;
      double tmp = *getcol(arg, &lastVal-pnode->tick);
      ...
         // pnode->tick.col1 = lastVal + i*(tmp/count);
         *getcol(arg, &pnode->tick) = lastVal + i*(tmp/count);
      ...
}

double *point_getCol1(void *arg, struct point *p) {
    return &p->col1;
}
double *point_getCol2(void *arg, struct point *p) {
    return &p->col2;
}
double *point_getCol3(void *arg, struct point *p) {
    return &p->col3;
}

int main() {
    crawlOne(plist, point_getCol2, NULL);
    crawlOne(plist, point_getCol3, NULL);
}
```

- In your case you can pass `offsetof` to members in `point` and dereference a pointer to `double*` at proper positions. This is not flexible and invites bugs, because it doesn't statically check types:

```
void crawlOne(List *plist, size_t coloffset)
{
  ...
      // tmp = lastVal-pnode->tick.col1;
      double tmp = *(double*)((char*)&lastVal-pnode->tick + coloffset);
      ...
         // pnode->tick.col1 = lastVal + i*(tmp/count);
         *(double*)((char*)&pnode->tick + coloffset) = lastVal + i*(tmp/count);
      ...
}

int main() {
    crawlOne(plist, offsetof(struct point, col1));
    crawlOne(plist, offsetof(struct point, col2));
}
```

- It's common to use a macro to ease up defining the function multiple times (only do if you really know what you are doing). Such tends to become hard to maintain, and is hard to debug:

```
#define DECLARE_CRAWL_ONE(FUNC, MEMBER) \
void FUNC(List *plist) \
{ \
      /* tmp = lastVal-pnode->tick.col1; */ \
      double tmp = lastVal-pnode->tick.MEMBER; \
      ... \
         /* pnode->tick.col1 = lastVal + i*(tmp/count); */ \
         lastVal-pnode->tick.MEMBER = lastVal + i*(tmp/count); \
      ... \
}

DECLARE_CRAWL_ONE(crawlOnecol1, col1)
DECLARE_CRAWL_ONE(crawlOnecol2, col2)
DECLARE_CRAWL_ONE(crawlOnecol2, col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize:

- You have a function `crawlOne(List *plist)` that locates some objects of type `struct point` and does something to their `col1` members.
- You would like to have a function `crawlSome(List *plist, int colnum)` which:

  - when called as `crawlSome(list, 1)` operates on `col1`
  - when called as `crawlSome(list, 2)` operates on `col2`
  - and so on.

By far the cleanest approach, as John Bollinger suggested in a comment, is to redesign `struct point` to contain an array instead of three separate members:

```
struct point {
    double col[3];
};

void crawlSome(List *plist, int colnum) {
    // ...
    pnode->tick.col[colnum] = ...;
}
```

This does mean that you have to change all existing code that uses `struct point`, which although straightforward could be tedious, but in the long term you have a cleaner and more efficient design.  I would do this if at all possible.

If you really cannot change the definition of `struct point` (e.g. it is used by third-party code that you can't modify), then you can't avoid hardcoding the member names somehow, since the names don't exist at runtime.  KamilCuk has suggested some options for this.  Another that I might think of is to pull out the hardcoding into a "column selector" function, so that it only has to be done at one place in your program.  It should not be too inefficient if it can be inlined.

```
inline double *select_column(struct point *pt, int colnum) {
    switch (colnum) {
        case 1: return &pt->col1;
        case 2: return &pt->col2;
        case 3: return &pt->col3;
        default: abort(); // or perhaps return NULL;
    }
}

void crawlSome(List *plist, int colnum) {
    // ...
    *select_column(&pnode->tick, colnum) = ...
}
```

This avoids the need to duplicate the code of `crawlOne` at all, with or without a macro.

If you want to reduce the repetition in defining `select_column`, you can use a macro with token pasting:

```
inline double *select_column(struct point *pt, int colnum) {
    switch (colnum) {
#define DO(N) case N: return &pt->col ## N ;
        DO(1)
        DO(2)
        DO(3)
#undef DO
        default: abort(); // or perhaps return NULL;
    }
}
```

If you want to make the selector a little nicer to use, you can wrap it in a macro:

```
#define COL(p, n) (*select_column(&(p), (n)))

void crawlSome(List *plist, int colnum) {
    // ...
    COL(pnode->tick, colnum) = ...;
}
```

Alternatively, a similar approach can be implemented with `offsetof`, though with the same lack of type checking that KamilCuk points out:

```
#include <stddef.h>

const size_t col_offsets[3] = {
    offsetof(struct point, col1),
    offsetof(struct point, col2),
    offsetof(struct point, col3)
};

#define COL(p, n) (*(double *)((char *)&(p) + col_offsets[(n)]))
```